# Model binding nested collections in editor templates

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an editor template that I use for a view model, `EditFeeContentViewModel`. This view model holds a collection that's added/removed through JavaScript. I'm adding the following HTML via microtemplating for whenever a new item is added so the model binding will work:

```
<script id="feeContentTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr id='RowContentId<%= ContentId%>'>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="ContentFeeViewModels.Index" value="<%= ContentId%>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ContentFeeViewModels[<%= ContentId%>].ContentId" value="<%= ContentId%>" />
            <%= ContentId%>
        </td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="ContentFeeViewModels[<%= ContentId%>].ContentName" value="<%= ContentName%>" />
            <%= ContentName%>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text"     name="ContentFeeViewModels[<%= ContentId%>].Allocation" value="<%= Allocation%>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"     name="ContentFeeViewModels[<%= ContentId%>].Comments" value="<%= Comments%>"/></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:removeContentRow('#RowContentId<%= ContentId%>')">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Now, this works fine for when my view model isn't nested. It submits to the controller, has all of the data intact, etc.

However, when it's nested, obviously the name is no longer correct and the model binding fails. Instead of `ContentFeeViewModels.Index`, I might need `FeeContents.ContentFeeViewModels.Index`.

Since this is being done through JavaScript, I don't know how I could use the HTML helpers to generate the names correctly. How can I find out if/where the view model is nested and generate a string to represent its location so the modelbinding happens correctly?

I thought about manually setting a string in `EditFeeContentViewModel` that a parent view model could set to represent the property name, but that seems cumbersome and error prone. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: This is very similar to a question I recently asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204288/razor-form-with-editable-collection-using-partial-with-knockout-template-integra/16385935#16385935. It's not exact, but perhaps you can get some application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you could use `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` to get the path value.

So my code now looks like:

```
var contentFeeModelPrefix = "";
if ("@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" != "") {
    contentFeeModelPrefix = "@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" + ".";
}
```

I can then use that variable in my JavaScript as the prefix to the various fields.